# CMake and CTest's default "test" command skips a specially named test

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest, ctest

I'm using CTest with CMake to run some tests. I use the `enable_testing()` command which provides me with a default command for `make test`. All of the tests in my subdirectory are accounted for (by doing  an `add_test` command) and `make test` works great, except one problem.

There is a certain test, which I've named `skip_test`, that I do NOT want being run when I do `make test`. I would like to add a custom target so I can run `make skip_test` and it will run that test.

I can do this by doing `add_custom_target(skip_test ...)` and providing CTest with the `-R` flag and telling it to look for files containing "skip_test" in their name. This also seems to work. My problem now is: how can I get the `make test` command to ignore `skip_test`?

If I try commenting out `enable_testing` and adding my own `add_custom_target(test ....)`, I get "No tests found!!!" now for either `make test` or `make skip_test`. I also tried making a Custom CTest file and adding `set(CTEST_CUSTOM_TESTS_IGNORE skip_test)`. This worked so that now `make test` ignored "skip_test", but now running `make skip_test` responds with "no tests found!!!".

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I found that in the Makefile generated by CMake, the target "make test" is defined. It runs ctest and has an extra $(ARGS) flag at the end. I found a "solution" to my problem is to manually type in "-E .*skip_test" and it skips my test named "skip_test". How can I tell CMake to append this to the "make test" target, which is automatically defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually used a different solution. Here is what I did. For the tests that I wanted to exclude, I used the following command when adding them:

"add_test( ..... CONFIGURATIONS ignore_flag)" where ignore_flag is whatever phrase you want. Then, in my CMakeLists.txt, when I define a custom target 
add_custom_target( ignore_tests ...)
I give it ctest .... -C ignore_flag

Now, make test WILL skip these tests! make ignore_Tests will run the ignored tests + the un-ignored tests, which I'm okay with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a way to do this entirely via CTest, but since you've tagged this question with "googletest", I assume you're using that as your test framework.  So, you could perhaps make use of Gtest's ability to [disable tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Temporarily_Disabling_Tests) and also to [run disabled tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Temporarily_Enabling_Disabled_Tests).

By changing the test(s) in question to have a leading `DISABLED_` in their name(s), these won't be run by default when you do `make test`.

You can then add your custom target which will invoke your test executable with the appropriate Gtest flags to run only the disabled tests:

```
add_custom_target(skip_test
    MyTestBinary --gtest_filter=*DISABLED_* --gtest_also_run_disabled_tests VERBATIM)
```

It's a bit of an abuse of the Gtest functionality - it's really meant to be used to temporarily disable tests while you refactor whatever to get the test passing again.  This beats just commenting out the test since it continues to compile it, and it gives a nagging reminder after running the suite that you have disabled tests.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable idea. I haven't tested it out yet, as I tried using Ctest configuration flags instead, but your idea might actually be easier. Thanks!