# Defining Variable in Custom Target for CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake file with two targets (say, target1 and target2) defined via "add_custom_target" at the top level of my source directory. I have some external projects in lower level directory. In the extneral project, a "TEST_COMMAND ${Test_Command_Variable}" is defined as part of an ExternalProject_Add().

I would like to change that vaiarble ${Test_Command_Variable} depending on whether I am using custom target1 or target2. Currently, ${Test_Command_Variable} is defined at the top level CMakeLists.txt before either custom targets are defined. I simply want to vary that variable depending on whether target1 or target2 is called. Is there any way to redefine that variable? Maybe do a conditional if statement dependent on whether target1 or target 2 is chosen (this seems like a trivial thing, but I can't find the way to access the "name" of the custom target!).

To clarify: I have two collections of tests. I want to type "make target1" and it runs my first collection of tests. I want to type "make target2" and it tests my second collection of tests. The problem is I also have an external project, where some of the tests are there. The external projects have a TEST_COMMAND(test_command_variable) that does not differentiate between target1 tests and target2 tests. I would like to be able to change that variable depending on whether I run "make target1" or "make target2".

Comment: What are you planning to do, with the redefined variable?

Comment: Can you please add some sample code from your `CMakeLists.txt`? If I understand this correctly you are generating a makefile environment with CMake, want to call `make target1` and - because the external project (testing `target1`?) has a dependency to `target1` - it should be executed with your target's name in the command line. If I'm right you should not use `ExternalProject_Add()` but `add_test(NAME target1 COMMAND TEST_COMMAND ${Target1Vars})` and use `ctest --build-and-test --build-target target1` (see also [CMake/Testing With CTest](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest))

Comment: The redefined variable is being passed into a TEST_COMMAND( my_variable_here) . This TEST_COMMAND spot handles the testing for an external project. The problem is, I sometimes want to test a certain collection of tests (target1 ) and another collection of tests (target2). I toggled the tests to be different with the add_test() command where I added a CONFIGURATIONS target1 or CONFIGURATIONS target2 in the add_test. The hope is that running make target1 will define a variable and pass  it onto the external project TEST_COMMAND(my_variable_here) which will then call the right subsets of tests.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working finally. I did something completely different to meet my objective. I abandoned the goal of trying to toggle variables depending on the target. To be clear, here was my objective:

"make target1" runs only tests in Group 1.

"make target2" runs only tests in Group 2.

I configured each of the tests as per [as per this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252228/cmake-and-ctests-default-test-command-skips-a-specially-named-test). My problem was that I had external projects I was trying to pass that variable down so it would toggle Group1 or Group 2 tests depending on the configuration defined at the top level. I knew passing ctest -C group1_configuration flag  (or group2_configuration flag for group2 tests)would work, but I couldn't seem to pass down to my external projects. Fortunately, my solution was "simple".

I wrote a shell script that would execute the correct ctest ... -C group1_configuration (or ctest ... -C group2_configuration) and called it test_script1.sh and test_script2.sh. These scripts would move through the build directory and call the aforementioned ctest command in each of the external projects build directories.   Then, in my custom target's I defined in the CMakeLists.txt I have it call the shell script and each custom target executes the right shell script, which move through the build directories calling the *correct* ctest command with the correct configuration flag in each project and external project.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. So your are doing something similar to [How to run ctest after building my project with cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115075/how-to-run-ctest-after-building-my-project-with-cmake)? Could you please add samples of your CMakeLists.txt and shell scripts? It would be interesting to see your solutions code. And I personally think you won't need an external script, because the `COMMAND`s of a custom target could handle everything.